# What's wrong with my WMI query?

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query

I'm trying to invert the following query:

```
using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT CommandLine FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = 4856")) {
    foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get()) {
        Debug.WriteLine(mo["CommandLine"]);
    }
}
```

Which returns the expected result:

> C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE

**INTO:**

```
using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT ProcessId FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine = 'C:\\Windows\\Explorer.EXE'")) {
    foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get()) {
        Debug.WriteLine(mo["ProcessId"]);
    }
}
```

Which throws an `Invalid query` exception and not the process id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just figured it out. I have to double up the slashes and escape characters in the path in the query.

Both the C# compiler and the WMI SQL implementation wants escaped slashes i guess. Stupid computers.

```
SELECT ProcessId FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine = 'C:\\\\windows\\\\explorer.EXE'
```